# How to decrease the stroke-width of md-progress-spinner in angular material 2?

Tags: css, angular, svg, angular-material2

I am using md-progress-spinner like this in my code :

```
<md-progress-spinner class="s-spinner" mode="indeterminate" color = "primary">
</md-progress-spinner>
```

How to change the stroke width of the svg rendered by md-progress spinner. By default the value of stroke width is 10 which is too big for my project.

Comment: strokeWidth="5px". Try having a look at the documentation...

Comment: Yes it works. I wasnt aware that we could add it like that

Comment: is your issue fixed or need additional help? @ShrutiAgarwal

Comment: @Aravind - I am able to change the stroke width. But I want to also decrease the diameter of the spinner. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal you can probably see this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0RHk8LU5X2Lze02iDN2a) and use the code in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documentation says,

```
@Input()
strokeWidth
Stroke width of the progress spinner. By default uses 10px as stroke width.
```

That is an input of the component, exactly like "mode" Jo just use it like this:

```
<md-progress-spinner class="s-spinner" strokeWidth="x" mode="indeterminate" color = "primary">
</md-progress-spinner>
```

Where x is the width you want.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the diameter of the spinner?